# Swfit: How to return to main thread after using Detached Task

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, thread-safety, task

I want to switch to background to load an image (or do any other task) and then return to Main thread to give a command to my view to display smth. Example:

```
func loadInBackground() async throws -> UIImage {
      Task.detached(priority: .background) {
        print("enter detachedTask")
        let image = try await self.loadedImage()
        print("exit detachedTask = \(image.size)")
        // ??? how to switch to main thread, so later I can do ???
        // imageView.image = image
      }
}

func loadedImage() async throws -> UIImage {
    let url = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg/1200px-Fronalpstock_big.jpg")!
      let request = URLRequest(url: url)
      let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
      let urlSessionResult = try await session.data(for: request) // returns (Data, URLResponse)
      let data = urlSessionResult.0
      guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
        throw TestError.imageLoading
      }
      return image
  }
```

P.S. I don't want to use:

```
Task {
        print("enter unstructuredTask")
        let image = try await loadedImage()
        imageView.image = image
        print("exit unstructuredTask")
      }
```

Because it doesn't actually switch to background thread, it does everything on the main thread (without impact on UI), but I need a background thread

Comment: `Task { @MainActor in`

Comment: @jnpdx could you provide a code snippet how to assign self.imageView.image = image using this method

Comment: Put your line inside the closure I suggested.

Answer (score -1):

use `@MainActor`

```
@MainActor
func backToMainThread() async {
    //set image view image here
}
```

or try this in the loadInBackground function

```
let mainThread = Task { @MainActor in
        //set image view image here
    }
await mainThread.value
```